# Не устанавливается gcc-6.3

Tags: gcc

Ubuntu 16.04

Выполнил команды:

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-6.3.0/gcc-6.3.0.tar.bz2
tar xzvf gcc-6.3.0.tar.bz2
cd gcc-6.3.0
./contrib/download_prerequisites

cd ~
mkdir gcc-build && cd gcc-build
../gcc-6.3.0/configure -v --prefix=$HOME/gcc-6.3.0

make 
make install
```

Все операции вроде бы выполнились успешно. Но если набрать gcc --version то показывает 6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в качестве prefix вы указали каталог `$HOME/gcc-6.3.0`:

> ../gcc-6.3.0/configure -v --prefix=$HOME/gcc-6.3.0

вот в него и была произведена установка после выполнения цели `install`.

так что ищите установленную программу в каталоге `$HOME/gcc-6.3.0/bin`:

```
$ $HOME/gcc-6.3.0/bin/gcc --version
```

---

и если в дальнейшем вам понадобится использовать программу данной версии, либо указывайте полный путь к ней, либо добавьте каталог `$HOME/gcc-6.3.0/bin` в начало переменной окружения `PATH` (не забыв отделить его двоеточием):

```
$ export PATH="$HOME/gcc-6.3.0/bin/gcc:$PATH"
$ gcc --version
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё решилось обновление до ubuntu 16.10

Comment: Мешать паркетную систему и установку из исходников - не к добру

Comment: не понял, почему? Что за паркетная система?

Comment: Ubuntu же устанавливает софт из пакетов. Пакеты, обычно, берёт из репозиториев.  Когда Вы скачали архив с исходниками, скомпилировали проект и выполнили make install, make установил софт, но ничего не сказал пакетному менеджеру (например, apt). Когда вы будете что-то устанавливать с помощью пакетного менеджера, то он будет считать, что у Вас не установлен пакет, который вы установили из исходников и перезапишет его. Хуже если вручную установленный пакет будет сильно отличаться от того, что требуется в качестве зависимости. apt будет считать, что у Вас нужная версия пакета, но это уже не так.